# Reload data continuously with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with some bootstrap cards. Information showing inside the card is retrieved from MySQL database.

**What I need**

I need these cards to be updated every 3 seconds without reloading the page. I know that Ajax is the way to do this (Update content without refreshing page). I am not familiar with Ajax. However, I tried as below

```js
<script>
  setInterval(
    (function x() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vTagInfoCall.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: "",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#inputFieldDisplay").html(result);
        }
      });
      return x;
    })(), 3000); 
</script>
```

Also I gave the following div with id `inputFieldDisplay` as below

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="inputFieldDisplay"></div>
</div>
```

**My Issue**

When I redirect to the mentioned page `vTagInfoCall.php` with all my php codes and contents, it is not loading anything to the `div` with `id` `inputFieldDisplay`. Did anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1**

Following is my `vTagInfoCall.php` file contents

```html
<?php ob_start();?>
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
<?php
    $tagQuery = "SELECT * FROM vtagdetails WHERE status = 0";
    $tagQueryExecute = mysqli_query($conn, $tagQuery);
    $openItems = mysqli_num_rows($tagQueryExecute);
    
    while($tagQueryRows = mysqli_fetch_array($tagQueryExecute)){
        
        $srNumber = $tagQueryRows['srNumber'];
        $Name = $tagQueryRows['Name'];
        $Code = $tagQueryRows['Code'];
        $customerName = $tagQueryRows['customers'];
        $Type = $tagQueryRows['Type'];

        session_start();
        echo '<form method="post"> <div class="card cardBodyStyle">
                  <div class="card-body" >
                    <div class="row">
                    
                    <input type="text" name= "srNum" value = "'.$srNumber.'" hidden>
                    
                    <input type="text" name= "tpCode" value = "'.$Code.'" hidden>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm"><i class="fab fa-500px"></i> '.$Name.'</div>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm"><i class="fas fa-atom"></i> '.$Type.'</div>

                    <div class="col-sm"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-spin"></i> '.$customerName.'</div>

                    </div>
                    
                    </div></div></form><br>';
        
    }
    
?>
```

**Edit 2**

It is showing the following error in console. Can someone help why is the error?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and methods, found out that I was using CDN of `slim` version of jQuery which caused this problem. Somehow there is some issue with Ajax in the `slim` version

I solved it by using the uncompressed version of jQuery CDN [from here](https://code.jquery.com/) and that is it!!

Answer (score 1):

I found two issues in code:

First in your script, please use below code:

```
<script>

  setInterval(x, 3000); 
function x() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vTagInfoCall.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: "",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#inputFieldDisplay").html(result);
        }
    })
}

</script>
```

Second one is remove `#` from your id of div because  `#` is just use to indicate id of element in jquery  and `.`(dot) for class name of element. Please update your code with below code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="inputFieldDisplay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Madhuri, I updated my php file content. Probably that file got some issue and that is why Ajax is not working. Could you please check if I am doing something wrong in that php file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly in **setInterval** function

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vTagInfoCall.php",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: "",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#inputFieldDisplay").html(result);
        }
    });
}, 3000);//time in milliseconds
```

And the problem is in Html div also as showed by madhuri and haisen. 
Whenever you used attributes(name,id,class whatever) you dont need to put dot,# or other symbols in the div or input.

So please fix it. I think it will work definitely.

```
<div id="#inputFieldDisplay"></div> // Wrong because of #

<div id="inputFieldDisplay"></div> //Right
```

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried, but not working. Probably something wrong with my php file. I updated my code with the content of php file. Could you please see if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to check console or alert in your brower.

Answer (score 0):

you html code with some incorrect in `id="#inputFieldDisplay"`

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="inputFieldDisplay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a typo happened from me. Anyway thank you haisen for highlighting it.